# No SQL Server PowerShell snapin installed despite installing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using SQL Server 2012 SP1 developer edition. Lately I had a need to use SQL Server snapin but PowerShell claims not to have one. I made a research on the internet but I didn't find any working solution. Is there any way I can add it to PowerShell?

`get-pssnapin -registered` output:

```
Name : CommonSnapIn          PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Common SnapIn
Name : ConfigurationSnapIn   PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Configuration SnapIn
Name : DefinitionSnapIn      PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Definition SnapIn
Name : DynoPortalSnapIn      PSVersion : 2.0 Description : DynoPortal SnapIn
Name : FoldersSnapIn         PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Folders SnapIn
Name : JournalSnapIn         PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Journal SnapIn
Name : MembershipSnapIn      PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Membership SnapIn
Name : MetadataSnapIn        PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Metadata SnapIn
Name : NotificationSnapIn    PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Notification SnapIn
Name : PersistenceSnapIn     PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Foundation Persistence SnapIn
Name : ReportingSnapIn       PSVersion : 2.0 Description : Reporting SnapIn
```

`add-PSSnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100` output:

```
PS C:\Users\CRDM and Secure 3> add-PSSnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100
add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'sqlservercmdletsnapin100' is not installed on this computer.    
At line:1 char:1  
+ add-PSSnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (sqlservercmdletsnapin100:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException  
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2011/03/31/loading-sql-server-snapins-into-your-powershell-session.aspx? That was the top hit from Googling: SQL Server snapin.

Comment: Yeah, didn't work :/. I'll do it again and post you the error message.

Comment: There wouldn't be much point, I can't say I know anything about powershell. Adding it to your question however, may be useful.

Comment: What does this return? `Get-Module -ListAvailable "sqlps"`

Comment: Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules


Not much.
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.0        SQLPS                               {Backup-SqlDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Disable-...

Comment: There you go, that's what you want.  In SQL Server 2012 SQLPS is the module, no longer requiring the use of the snapin.  Just do `Import-Module "sqlps"` and you should be good from there.

Comment: @Skylerdw You're quite welcome!  I've added this as an answer, as it appears to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 the PowerShell functionality delivered by the product came in the form of a PowerShell module, so therefore you no longer need to work with the snapins.

To consume the SQL Server PowerShell module, you simply need to do this:

```
Import-Module "sqlps"
```

Or if you are using PowerShell v3+ then you just need to reference a member of that module and it'll be automatically loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

We're now several years later, but I stumbled upon this question looking for an answer.

Nowadays the
import-module SqlServer
works great!

Afterwards you can use the invoke-sqlcmd query.